# How to combine a vector and a raster file?

Tags: raster, vector, grass-gis

I want to combine a raster and a vector file. After combining, can I query on the resulting map to obtain a specific area? How?

Comment: No, I don't think you can or should combine raster and vector files. That defeats half the purpose of GIS

Comment: Combine for what purpose? Just a combined visualisation can be accomplished in any ol' GIS program - pick your weapon from a wide range of free and open source to expensive proprietary packages. I like QGis myself. If you want to do more than just visualisation, then you will need to elaborate on your intent a bit more before anyone could provide a useful answer.

Comment: I am using: v.db.select map=PHL_adm1 where=NAME_1='Bulacan'


My vector map is over the raster map. I want to select the part of the raster map under the polygon(NAME_1='Bulacan') of a vector. Is it possible to do?

Comment: To transfer raster values to a vector map, use for example http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.what.rast.html . Then use v.report to get statistics.

Comment: So this is basically a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/how-to-select-a-raster-file-that-is-under-a-polygon-in-a-vector-file ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to identify a common area that exists on both the vector and the raster, I suggest you convert the vector to raster. There are a few things to consider when you do this;

- make the spatial extents of the new raster the same as the original one
- use the same raster cell size.

Then you can identify a common area between the two rasters using a few different techniques. One method is to assign certain values to cells within the new raster. For example you could make your new raster have a value of 1 where the vector object exists, and 0 elsewhere. Then you could multiply the rasters by each other, and the product (a third raster) will give you the intersection.

Comment: I used `v.to.rast` to convert my vector map to raster map. How can I "assign certain values to cells within the new raster"? What is the script for it?

Comment: What values are the raster cells? You could reclassify them using `r.reclass` See http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/r.reclass.html