# How to select a raster file that is under a polygon in a vector file?

Tags: raster, vector, grass-gis

I am using:
v.db.select map=PHL_adm1 where=NAME_1='Bulacan'

My vector map is over the raster map. I want to select the part of the raster map under the polygon(NAME_1='Bulacan') of a vector. Is it possible to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with the selection? Do you want to create a new layer from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine a vector and a raster file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/how-to-combine-a-vector-and-a-raster-file)

Comment: I am not a grass person. But have tried to use it. Here is someplace you might find some answers until someone knowledgable responds...http://www.grassbook.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here is the procedure to do that:

v.to.rast - convert vector to raster.
r.mask - create a mask from the raster.
r.resample - to create a new raster clipped by the mask.

Comment: After comparing the initial raster map and the resulting raster map from r.resample, I noticed that the map from r.resample had produced a map with altered values. The portion within the polygon of the initial and resulting map differed in values. How was that possible if the r.resample just crops a map from the mask?